# Trying to make Gnome sort recursive

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, recursion

I was given the following block of code

`def sort(a):
    """Sort list a into ascending order by value.
    Adapted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort#Code.
    """
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(a):
        if pos == 0 or a[pos] >= a[pos-1]:
            pos += 1
        else:
            a[pos], a[pos-1] = a[pos-1], a[pos]
            pos -= 1`

and need to make implment it the same in python, but recursively instead of iteratively. so far I have

`def sort(a,pos=0):
    if(pos<len(a)):
        return
    else:
        if(pos==0 or a[pos]>= a[pos-1]):
            sort(a,pos+1)
        else:
            a[pos],a[pos-1]= a[pos-1],a[pos]
            pos=pos-1`

can anyone help me out

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165)

Answer (score 0):

You should not return when `pos` is less than `len(a)`, and you should make a recursive call with `pos - 1` after the swap:

```
def sort(a, pos=0):
    if pos < len(a):
        if pos == 0 or a[pos] >= a[pos - 1]:
            sort(a, pos + 1)
        else:
            a[pos], a[pos - 1] = a[pos - 1], a[pos]
            sort(a, pos - 1)
```